# Using Lucene's API, can I boost terms?

Tags: lucene, full-text-search

With Lucene's query parser, it's possible to boost terms (causing them to weight higher in the search results) by appending "^n", e.g. "apple^5 pie" would assign five times more importance to the term "apple". Is it possible to do this when constructing a query using the API? Note that I'm not wanting to boost fields or documents, but individual terms within a field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply need to use the `setBoost(float)` method of the `Query` class.

For example

```
TermQuery tq1 = new TermQuery(new Term("text", "term1"));
tq1.setBoost(5f);
TermQuery tq2 = new TermQuery(new Term("text", "term2"));
tq2.setBoost(0.8f);
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.add(tq1, Occur.SHOULD);
query.add(tq2, Occur.SHOULD);
```

This is equivalent to parsing the query `text:term1^5 text:term2^0.8`.

Comment: Thanks! Now why couldn't I find that… all I found were document boost and field boost. Now I feel dumb for having had to ask. But thanks!

Comment: this api doesn't work with lucene 6.. you have to wrap around a boostquery? kinda wasteful? you know other way?